# Java: Error deserialising an aggregate object from JSON (HAS-A relationship)

Tags: java, jackson, deserialization, pojo

I am getting a `Can not set com.google.api.services.androidmanagement.v1.model.HardwareInfo field com.google.api.services.androidmanagement.v1.model.Device.hardwareInfo to java.util.LinkedHashMap` error when I am converting a Google API Services [Device](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/androidmanagement/v1/java/latest/com/google/api/services/androidmanagement/v1/model/Device.html) object to JSON (using Jackson 2.10.0) and reading back from it in a test. The [Device](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/androidmanagement/v1/java/latest/com/google/api/services/androidmanagement/v1/model/Device.html) object consists of objects of Google API Services types [HardwareInfo](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/androidmanagement/v1/java/latest/com/google/api/services/androidmanagement/v1/model/HardwareInfo.html), [MemoryInfo](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/androidmanagement/v1/java/latest/com/google/api/services/androidmanagement/v1/model/MemoryInfo.html), etc. that seem to be failing since the ObjectMapper is reading them as LinkedHashMap instead of the actual types. I tried searching on StackOverflow and went through a load of articles but none of them seem to be addressing this `JsonMappingException`.

What am I doing wrong and how do I fix this? I tried using Mixin since this is a Google POJO and I cannot modify properties directly, but wasn't able to resolve the problem. Any help regarding this would be greatly appreciated! Thanks.

The complete test code is:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAutoDetect;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.PropertyAccessor;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.google.api.services.androidmanagement.v1.model.Device;
import com.google.api.services.androidmanagement.v1.model.HardwareInfo;
import com.google.api.services.androidmanagement.v1.model.MemoryInfo;
import com.google.api.services.androidmanagement.v1.model.SoftwareInfo;
import com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap;

/**
 * TODO: Document this class.
 */
public class MyTest {


    @Test
    public void myTest() {

        // code to build the test Device object 
        Device device = new Device();
        final List<String> prevNameList = Arrays.asList("prev-1", "prev-2", "prev-3");

        final HardwareInfo hwInfo = new HardwareInfo();
        hwInfo.setBrand("hwinfo-brand");
        hwInfo.setDeviceBasebandVersion("hwinfo-baseband-version");
        hwInfo.setManufacturer("test-manufacturer");
        hwInfo.setModel("hwinfo-model");
        hwInfo.setSerialNumber("hwinfo-serial-no");
        hwInfo.setHardware("hwinfo-hardware");

        final MemoryInfo memoryInfo = new MemoryInfo();
        memoryInfo.setTotalInternalStorage(123456789L);
        memoryInfo.setTotalRam(123456789L);

        final Map<String, String> propsMap = ImmutableMap.of(
                "prop1", "x86",
                "prop2", "ARM",
                "prop3", "Intel Itanium-based");

        device.setPolicyName("test-policy-name");
        device.setAppliedPolicyName("test-applied-policy-name");
        device.setEnrollmentTokenName("test-enrollment-token-name");
        device.setEnrollmentTokenData("test-enrollment-token-data");
        device.setEnrollmentTime("2020-01-01T00:00:00.000Z");
        device.setLastPolicySyncTime("2020-01-01T00:00:00.000Z");
        device.setLastStatusReportTime("2020-01-01T00:00:00.000Z");
        device.setLastPolicyComplianceReportTime("2020-01-01T00:00:00.000Z");
        device.setUserName("test-user-name");
        device.setName("test-name");

        device.setPreviousDeviceNames(prevNameList);
        device.setSystemProperties(propsMap);
        device.setHardwareInfo(hwInfo);
        device.setMemoryInfo(memoryInfo);

        ObjectMapper mapper = buildMapper();
        try {
            // code to convert object to JSON
            final String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(device);
            final String jsonHwInfo = mapper.writeValueAsString(device);
            System.out.println(json);

            // code to read JSON to object
            final Device deserializedDevice = mapper.readValue(json, Device.class);
            System.out.println(deserializedDevice);
        } catch (IOException | JsonProcessingException e) {
            e.print
        }
    }

    private static ObjectMapper buildMapper() {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.FIELD, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY);
        mapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);
        mapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.FIELD, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY);

        return mapper;
    }

}
```

The output for this test is:

```
{"appliedPolicyName":"test-applied-policy-name","enrollmentTime":"2020-01-01T00:00:00.000Z","enrollmentTokenData":"test-enrollment-token-data","enrollmentTokenName":"test-enrollment-token-name","hardwareInfo":{"brand":"hwinfo-brand","deviceBasebandVersion":"hwinfo-baseband-version","hardware":"hwinfo-hardware","manufacturer":"test-manufacturer","model":"hwinfo-model","serialNumber":"hwinfo-serial-no"},"lastPolicyComplianceReportTime":"2020-01-01T00:00:00.000Z","lastPolicySyncTime":"2020-01-01T00:00:00.000Z","lastStatusReportTime":"2020-01-01T00:00:00.000Z","memoryInfo":{"totalInternalStorage":123456789,"totalRam":123456789},"name":"test-name","policyName":"test-policy-name","previousDeviceNames":["prev-1","prev-2","prev-3"],"systemProperties":{"prop1":"x86","prop2":"ARM","prop3":"Intel Itanium-based"},"userName":"test-user-name"}
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not set com.google.api.services.androidmanagement.v1.model.HardwareInfo field com.google.api.services.androidmanagement.v1.model.Device.hardwareInfo to java.util.LinkedHashMap (through reference chain: com.google.api.services.androidmanagement.v1.model.Device["hardwareInfo"])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.wrapWithPath(JsonMappingException.java:394)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.wrapWithPath(JsonMappingException.java:353)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.ContainerDeserializerBase.wrapAndThrow(ContainerDeserializerBase.java:181)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.MapDeserializer._readAndBindStringKeyMap(MapDeserializer.java:539)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.MapDeserializer.deserialize(MapDeserializer.java:364)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.MapDeserializer.deserialize(MapDeserializer.java:29)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4202)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3205)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3188)
    at com.mobileiron.polaris.service.androidwork.androidmanagementapi.DeviceTest.myTest(DeviceTest.java:89)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:104)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:645)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:851)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1177)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:129)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:112)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:756)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:610)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:387)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:382)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:340)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:289)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1293)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1218)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1133)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1104)
    at com.intellij.rt.testng.IDEARemoteTestNG.run(IDEARemoteTestNG.java:66)
    at com.intellij.rt.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:110)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set com.google.api.services.androidmanagement.v1.model.HardwareInfo field com.google.api.services.androidmanagement.v1.model.Device.hardwareInfo to java.util.LinkedHashMap
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:167)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:171)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.set(UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.java:81)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.set(Field.java:764)
    at com.google.api.client.util.FieldInfo.setFieldValue(FieldInfo.java:245)
    at com.google.api.client.util.FieldInfo.setValue(FieldInfo.java:206)
    at com.google.api.client.util.GenericData.put(GenericData.java:103)
    at com.google.api.client.util.GenericData.put(GenericData.java:47)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.MapDeserializer._readAndBindStringKeyMap(MapDeserializer.java:534)
    ... 30 more
```